# What is the difference between data entries and data records?

Tags: database

I was looking through my lecture notes, and came across this slide. I am confused what a data entry vs a data record. I know the data record is the entire tuple, but I am unsure about the data entry.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data entry in this case is the record contained in the index: typically, it is a pair (value of the key, reference to the tuple), where the reference to a tuple can be either a TID, Tuple Identifier, or some other way of referring to a tuple.

Answer (score 10):

**Data records** is a complete row of your database stored somewhere in the filesystem.

**Data entries** only stores the columns that you specified in the index. Data entries usually keep a pointer to the data record in the filesystem where the record resides